# Duas condições em consulta SQL com Laravel 4

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

Preciso fazer uma consulta ao MySQL com duas condições. Tentei fazer assim:

```
$query=DB::table('veteranos')->where('ra', '2300')->where('flag', 0)->pluck('ra');
```

Desta forma, a segunda condição não está funcionando, ou seja, a consulta pega valores diferentes de 0 para `flag`.
Qual seria a forma correta de faze esta consulta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer duas funções. A segunda função recebe como parâmetro o resultado da primeira consulta.

```
DB::table('veteranos')->where('ra', '2300')
            ->where(function($query){
                return $query
                          ->where('flag', 0)->pluck('ra');
```